# How can I dynamically recreate / change Vanilla JS Datepicker element option(s)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object

I am using a Vanilla JS Datepicker on a page that has a dropdown for multiple store locations, each of which have varying days of operation. Some being closed weekends, others being open weekends, some being closed Sunday, open Saturday, etc.

My objective is to create a single datepicker using an event listener on a selecte element with options for various locations.

In the event listener, I wish to call a function that will create the datepicker with the options for the days to be closed for that given location.

What I am experiencing is when the first location is selected, the datepicker populates according to that locations days of operation. Subsequent changes to the select though does not change the calender from original location. I am passing an array to the function that creates the datepicker.

I verified the array passed to the datepicker function changes with each option change, but it is not reflected on the calender.

```
let date1 = document.querySelector('input[name="Service_Date"]');
let closeDays = [];

function d1(days){
let serviceDate = new Datepicker(date1, {
autohide:true,
nextArrow:"<span class='fa fa-chevron-right'></span>",
prevArrow:"<span class='fa fa-chevron-left'></span>",
minDate:"today",
daysOfWeekDisabled:days
});    
}

closeDays = [0];
d1(closeDays);
closeDays = [];
closeDays = [0,6]
d1(closeDays);
```

The above code will generate an initial datepicker with Sundays (0) disabled after the 1st function call, but after the 2nd call, the disabled days should be Sunday and Saturday, but they are not.

I tried various attempts at calling the function, consoling out the array and the function parameter. They both change, but not the calendar.

Comment: There is no built-in JS `Datepicker` class, it has to be a third-party library. So read its documentation to find out how to customize it.

Comment: Thank you. I did. But it was of no help.

https://mymth.github.io/vanillajs-datepicker/#/

Comment: I suggest you keep the settings for each location in an object. Then when you want to create the datepicker for a particular location, you can extract the options from that object.

Comment: `{"location 1": { settings...}, "location 2": { settings...} and so on}`

Comment: I solved the problem. What I did was to declare serviceDate outside the function. Then, inside the function I added a conditional that if serviceDate != '' then serviceDate.destroy()    Your suggestion to look at the documentation encouraged me to do so, and I looked at the API, saw the destroy() method and used it. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

```
let date1 = document.querySelector('input[name="Service_Date"]');
let closeDays = [];
let serviceDate = '';

function d1(days){
if(serviceDate != ''){
serviceDate.destroy();
}
serviceDate = new Datepicker(date1, {
autohide:true,
nextArrow:"<span class='fa fa-chevron-right'></span>",
prevArrow:"<span class='fa fa-chevron-left'></span>",
minDate:"today",
daysOfWeekDisabled:days
});    
}

closeDays = [0];
d1(closeDays);
closeDays = [];
closeDays = [0,6]
d1(closeDays);
```

Comment: Please add some description to toy answer, please read [answer]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).